# AttributeError: 'gurobipy.QuadExpr' object has no attribute 'getVar'

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

I am trying to solve a MILP problem using Python with Gurobi Solver. When I solve the model with the constraint (attached below), it appears the error like this: "AttributeError: 'gurobipy.QuadExpr' object has no attribute 'getVar'".
Could you help me to fix this error? Thank you in advance!

`mdl.addConstrs((t[i,k] * X[i,j,k] - te1[i] <= 5) >> (z1[i,k] == 1) for i,j,k in arcos if i != 0 and i != 23)`

> where: t[i,j]: a continuous variable;
> X[i,j,k], z1[i,k]: binary variables;
> te1[i]: a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gurobi documentation demonstrates how to add indicator constraints: [Model.addGenConstrIndicator()](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/py_model_agc_indicator.html)
And the documentation for [Model.addConstrs()](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/py_model_addconstrs.html) also has an example for adding multiple indicator constraints in one call:

```
model.addConstrs((x[i] == 1) >> (y[i] + z[i] <= 5) for i in range(5))
```

In general, you need to define a binary variable that serves as the *indicator*. Your constraints seem to be the other way around, with a condition being fulfilled resulting in whether an indicator variable is set.

Answer (score -1):

This is indeed not a very informative error message. Developers are notorious for not paying much attention to formulating good, meaningful error messages. They should. A better error message could have prevented this post.

Now to the underlying issue. An indicator constraint has the following structure:

```
binary variable = 0 ==> linear constraint
```

or

```
binary variable = 1 ==> linear constraint
```

You need to reformulate things to fit into this scheme. Or use a big-M formulation.